# Comparing several table columns

Tags: performance, matlab, loops

I have two tables with a different number of rows and three columns. If, for a certain row, the values in column one and two are the same as in the other table, I want to select the values from the third column. Below is a sample code that works, but since in reality, I have over 2 million rows in both tables, it takes a very long time to run. **Is there a way to speed up the code by getting rid of the loops?**

```
MOOSE2=table(['2010/03/30 00:30:00'; '2010/03/22 18:00:00' ; '2010/04/21 18:30:00';  '2010/02/20 02:20:00'; '2010/03/10 02:30:00'],[5 ;8 ;4; 9 ;7],[10; 11 ;12 ;13 ;14]);
Lion2=table(['2010/03/30 00:30:00';  '2010/04/21 18:30:00';  '2010/03/20 22:00:00';  '2010/03/10 02:00:00'],[5;4;6;7],[17;12;11;14]);
[sMOOSE,~]=size(MOOSE2);
[sLion,~]=size(Lion2);
dmoose=[];
dlion=[];
for i=1:sLion
    for j=1:sMOOSE
        if (MOOSE2.(1)(j,:)==Lion2.(1)(i,:))&(MOOSE2.(2)(j,:)==Lion2.(2)(i,:))
        dmoose=[dmoose;MOOSE2.(3)(j,:)];
        dlion=[dlion;Lion2.(3)(i,:)];
        end
    end
end
```

Which gives me the correct output of

```
dlion =

    17
    12
dmoose =

    10
    12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect scenario for [intersect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.intersect.html):

```
MOOSE2=table(['2010/03/30 00:30:00'; '2010/03/22 18:00:00' ; '2010/04/21 18:30:00';  '2010/02/20 02:20:00'; '2010/03/10 02:30:00'],[5 ;8 ;4; 9 ;7],[10; 11 ;12 ;13 ;14]);
Lion2=table(['2010/03/30 00:30:00';  '2010/04/21 18:30:00';  '2010/03/20 22:00:00';  '2010/03/10 02:00:00'],[5;4;6;7],[17;12;11;14]);

[~,moose_index,lion_index] = intersect(MOOSE2(:,1:2),Lion2(:,1:2),'rows');
dlion = Lion2.Var3(lion_index)
dmoose = MOOSE2.Var3(moose_index)
```

Comment: Minor caveat: I think this assumes that the combinations of key values are unique in the inputs. (i.e. it does one-to-one matching instead of many-to-many.) If there may be duplicates in the input, I think you'll need to do an inner join instead of an intersect?